# SignalR for Desktop-Web Application (C#, .NET/Azure, WinForms)

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, winforms, signalr

I'm developing a Web App with a Desktop UI that is going to use several Azure Packages within Azure Servers (The basis of the Application being Web Based), and WinForms as the Desktop User Interface for the individual Clients to interact and control the flow of content.

**The App's purpose is to allow users to send files and links to each other and using Push Notifications, Cloud Storage, (and Custom UI), to make this an instantaneous process. When receiving the Notification, the Client may be able to preview their File/Link (Website), and may be able to download/copy the link.**

If I were to compare my app's function, it would be similar to *Discord*, which is Web App on a Browser, but also an downloadable variant. The downloadable variant is what I would want as a model for my app: Web Based, but Desktop UI.

The process in Primitive terms goes as this:

1. A Client opens a file and using the User Directory, "sends" the file
   to another Client.
2. This is actually the First Client sending the file to the other
   Client's Blob Container, identity held by AD B2C,
3. and after receiving the file, multiple Function(s) take File
   details (sender Client, time received, File/Website Type),
4. and send it in a Customizable Push Notification to the Client
   receiving it, who gets it in a Desktop UI Notification UI.)
5. The Receiving Client can then preview/stream it from the server as Blob Storage allows,
   and even download/copy the File/Link.

I understand **Azure AD B2C** can be used for registering users, **Azure Blob Storage** storing "sent" files, and **Azure Functions** for processing and continuously generating containers for each individual registered Client and processing each individual notification sent between Clients, however, I'm resting on the Fence over 2 options for my instant messaging technology.

I have been looking at **SignalR** for sometime and due to its Instantaneous behavior, and being associated with Azure, it's a good choice. However, there is lacking documentation on WinForms Web-based Apps using SignalR ( it appears to be more Website Focused, though people have stated that they have done Console Apps with it, etc) , and others have been recommending **WCF** as it's older and firmer, and has been said to work more with Windows Desktop Apps by default.

I'm leaning towards SignalR since it doesn't require server infrastructure maintenance and no heavy server functions Need to be done.

So can it be done, if so and so where would I Start?

***TL.DR/Summary:*** I'm creating a web based Application on Azure Infrastructure, and my Clients will use an Installed WinForms Program to control the flow of content, "send" content, etc. This is like signing into a Website and receiving live notifications, so may the same be done with Is SignalR with Client Desktop Apps,or is WCF more appropriate?

[Primitive Diagram of App Functioning with Azure, including SignalR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmoSN.png)

Comment: *However, there is lacking documentation on WinForms Web-based Apps using SignalR*: that is caused by the fact that documentation is geared towards the most common scenario's. There is no reason why it can't be used for a desktop application. I have done it myself once using an older signalr version. In the end it doesn't matter what process is hosting the signalr component.

Comment: Thank you very much for you input! I will look into it from a deeper perspective!